# Can we make 101 almost perfect banknotes from 100?

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

*Disclaimer. The practical execution of the algorithm in question might be illegal in certain jurisdictions, and is thus strongly discouraged by the poser of the problem.*

This [recent post on the Muffin problem](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2018/06/21/muffins-and-integers/) made me think of the following question.

> > Can we cut 100 banknotes into pieces of size at least $10\%$ each, and reassemble them into 101 banknotes of size $100\pm2\%$ each?

So each original banknote is cut into at most $10$ pieces of substantial size, and each new banknote also consists of at most $10$ pieces.
The patterns on these newly formed banknotes should match, so we also demand, say, that no part of a banknote appears twice on a new banknote.
Of course, these numbers are quite ad hoc, I'm happy to see any similar result.
Note that if we don't require each piece to be at least $10\%$, then it is easy to make the trick by cutting each banknote into only two (sometimes very unequal) parts.
I also wonder if non-vertical cuts might help, but I would like to keep the pieces simply connected regions bounded by Jordan curves.

Also, is there some implication between this question and the Muffin problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I've tried solving the problem...

Comment: There was an exhibit like this at the San Francisco Exploratorium.

Comment: That sounds interesting - can you provide more detail?

Comment: @domotorp:  OK... HOW have you tried to solve the problem?  What are some of your intermediate results?  Please show us.

Comment: I wrote down all that I know about the problem. My only "intermediate result", as you can see above, is that this is possible if the pieces can be arbitrarily small, even if we require that each new note consists of exactly two pieces.

Comment: Have you tried going at it with a pair of scissors and some tape?

Comment: Note that non-vertical cuts are necessary to solve the problem. If only vertical cuts are allowed (so the banknotes are essentially 1D segments), then you cannot make cuts in the leftmost 10% of each banknote, and hence you have at most 100 "leftmost 10%" parts (and each banknote must have one).

Comment: Somewhat similar: [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510091/generating-valid-currency-by-cutting-notes)

Comment: +1 for the "Illegal" tag :D

Comment: In the U.S., mutilated bills satisfying certain criteria can be exchanged for intact bills at banks or, in the case of badly damaged bills, by submitting them to the Bureau of Engraving and Printing. https://www.bep.gov/services/currencyredemption.html I wouldn't be shocked if the BEP has seen attempts to fraudulently "make money" in this fashion. Note that the task facing the real-world fraudster is made more difficult by serial numbers and other security features.

Comment: I don't think serial numbers should pose a problem, if you have enough banknotes and also accept that the missing part can go through a number. I also cannot imagine any other security feature that would be apparent to a person. Probably putting the serial number all over the banknote digitally in an eps-net would protect against this method when a machine checks the validity, but I doubt this is used in any currency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This (top half) is a way to cut 49 banknotes into pieces of at least 10% each and (bottom half) reassemble them to 50 "98%" banknotes. Let $w$ denote the width and $h$ the height. The bills below have an aspect ratio of 1:2 but this isn't necessary.

[image]

<sub>([SVG source code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/3adbddab06a16f12483b36c6f8271d32/raw/c9426aadcb135c8d488281f7712089fedef8be05/bill.svg))</sub>

I hope that it's clear how the pattern continues in the center; simply use each leftover piece together with the next one (which is matching in color) to form a 98% bill; the size of the square gap is $\frac{w}{10}$ by $\frac{h}{5}$.

The two outer columns on both sides are trickier, because it's impossible get rid of the corners with the same scheme as used in the center. Therefore, we cut strokes with width $\frac{w}{5}$, moving $\frac{h}{10}$ downwards each time. Reassembling them gives 'inlets' of $\frac{w}{5}$ by $\frac{h}{10}$.

Note that all bills get cut into two pieces, except for the two with the large light blue part (top left and top right) which are cut into three pieces.

Comment: this doesnt really make sense because 1. thats not 50 notes (or 49 even) and 2. you dont show the reuse of the 2 block sections, which would be required for a valid solution

Comment: @StevenPenny I too was confused by the figure at first. The image shows the 49 notes before cutting and the colors show the way they are reassembled into 50 notes. The hatched squares, as explained in the text, do not indicate missing or discarded paper, but are instead meant to be divided half-and-half into the colored regions above and below. Presumably this will be fixed in the next version of this answer.

Comment: @j.c. again, it doesnt show 50 or even 49 notes, it shows at most 35

Comment: @StevenPenny The center column of rectangles with dashed outlines is supposed to indicate that some additional columns (4 of them if I'm counting correctly) are not shown; there is a not-too-complicated pattern of cutting and gluing shown in the 3rd and 5th columns which can be extended to those hidden columns. I do believe that the answer should include more textual explanation for the image as I did spend quite a bit of time figuring all of this out.

Comment: I've updated the figure. @StevenPenny I've updated the picture and added some additional explanation. Please let me know I still need to be clearer on some points.

Comment: now theres 59...

Comment: @StevenPenny no, there are four columns not shown.

Comment: @Glorfindel why

Comment: Look at the bill in top row. The vertical line in the third column is at 20%; in the four hidden columns it is at 30%, 40%, 50% and 60%. The 70% is shown again. Also, you can't cut 59 100% bills and reassemble them in 60 98% bills; you'd have 20% of a bill left somewhere.

Comment: To be absolutely explicit: the new version of the image now shows both the pre-cutting bills (top 5 rows) and the post-cutting reassembled bills (bottom 5 rows). Four columns of bills are omitted in both and replaced by the central column of dashed rectangles. The answer and images, I think, are much clearer now.

Comment: Actually, I think that the middle part is a bit over complicated. After you manage to get the two side-strips, you can just finish off by vertical cuts. Isn't that simpler?

Comment: Yes, that'd work as well. It is however less easy to draw convincingly.

Answer (score 2):

This video http://thekidshouldseethis.com/post/62804856022 shows a possible solution (well, not for banknotes but for chocolate and one piece is only about 4% in size). This is a variant of Paul Curry's paradox described in Martin Gardner's book "Mathematics, Magic and Mystery": http://store.doverpublications.com/0486203352.html
In fact some real money was done from this paradox: a plastic version of Gardner's square was made in China and sold in stores. See Gardner's interview https://www.jstor.org/stable/25653710

However, a better way to make money is provided by Banach-Tarski paradox: A gold sphere can be chopped into a finite number of chunks, and these chunks
can then be put together again to yield two gold spheres, each of which has the same size as the one that just went into pieces. See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202309 (The Banach-Tarski paradox or what mathematics and religion have in common, by Volker Runde). The history of this theorem can be colourfully traced through the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05659 (From Poland to "Petersburg": The Banach-Tarski Paradox in Bely's Modernist Novel, by Noah Giansiracusa and Anastasia Vasilyeva).

**P.S.** Even if we forget about preserving the pattern on the banknote, the Banach-Tarski paradox doesn't work for planar banknotes. As mentioned in  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016800720300126X (On the Warsaw interactions of logic and mathematics in the years 1919–1939, by Roman Duda):

> This is the famous Banach–Tarski paradox. By the way, one can
>   ask about money: can a banknote produce two of its kind? It is a problem in applied mathematics, but the answer is, unfortunately negative: no bounded set in the plane can have such a paradoxical decomposition [41, footnote 1 on p. 218].

And [41] is Adolphe Lindenbaums article "Contributions à l'étude de l'espace métrique":  http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv8i1p16bwm

Comment: These well-known instances are not so related to my problem, because they don't preserve the pattern on the banknote in any way. I also wrote that the pieces should be simply connected regions bounded by Jordan curves to exclude BT type solutions.

Comment: The validity of  the approach based on Banach-Tarski depends on the underlying model of set theory...